# MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'UnityEngine.Behaviour.get_isActiveAndEnabled'.Unity3D(4.5 and 4.6) + Vuforia 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm working on an Augmented Reality project with Unity3D(4.5 and 4.6) using Vuforia 5

I have downloaded the latest vuforia sdk from the Vuforia site

Even I have downloaded the sample project.
[image]

I have imported the Imagetarget sample into the project.
[image]

I have added the licence key 
[image]

Added it into the ARCamera->Vuforia Behaviour(Script)-App licence Key
[image]

But I run the program it not displaying the camera view along with it its shows the following error
[image]

Can anybody help me out solving this issue please.

Comment: I would suggest you to copy paste the console errors in the question instead of posting the screenshot.

Comment: Check [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/issues-and-bugs/vuforia-5-and-unity-454f1-error)